# how to run my index.js without using nodemon on nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, nodemon

I'm having problems running my index.js manually instead of using the nodemon command. Using nodemon, my application runs normally, but without it i get this error:

`Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension. (Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)`

and
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I tried to set type to module as the error recommends, but then I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\euler\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\Thaiane-Alimentos\server\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.`

And I don't know how to solve it anymore, because in my mind, if I migrate computers or put the server on some hosting, these errors will appear. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You shouldn't use both `import` and `require`

Comment: thanks, i'll try to change to `import`